# Why won't my button text align vertically in the middle of the button [CSS]?

Tags: css, button, text, alignment, center

I am trying to style with CSS my Navigation bar. I tried it previously with a **table**, which works fine, however I am now trying to do it with an **un-ordered list** and styling it. Whatever I do, the text does not go to the middle of the button.

I tried using: 
 **- text-align: center; 

 - vertical-align: middle; 

 - position: absolute

 - float:center**

You may see the buttons in my code [In this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anidimitrovaaanidimitrova/tbh62k9q/) or below:

```
.mainheader nav {
    height: 85px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 41.55%; /* margin for Chrome */
    -moz-margin-start: 41.8%; /* margin for Mozilla firefox */
}

.mainheader nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainheader nav ul li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas you might have.

Comment: you mean vertically center the text? I know that's been answered a million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited{
    color:#AB6F80;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    /* Come back here to assign height */
    height:71px;
   line-height:71px;
}
```

line-height added - this will work fine with one line of text in link... http://jsfiddle.net/tbh62k9q/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could change the code by removing the height and having just padding. 
Like this:

```
.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited{
   color:#AB6F80;
   display: block;
   padding: 33px 20px;
   /* Come back here to assign height */
```

}

Or add `line-height` the same as height of the element.

Comment: line-height is something I haven't tried and I didn't know as I am still a newbie. Just creating my first website and trying to make it all by myself with researches, videos etc :)) this is the best way to learn things :) and stackoverflow is one of my main "books" on the matter =)) Thanks!! =)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to wrap the button in a div, remove the float and make the margin auto. Working example: [http: /
/jsfiddle.net/madcowley/ondptw5h/](http://jsfiddle.net/madcowley/ondptw5h/)

```
.centerme {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="centerme">
 <img...
</div>
```

Also see [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css) for some more explanation, in case it's helpful.